# Onclick event runs twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can't seem to work out why my `onclick()` event fires twice when the user clicks on a star.

If the user clicks on the first star in the first set, it should output `1` and `0.5` to the console, but instead it outputs `1` and `undefined` and `1` and `0.5`.

The first value is supposed to represent the value of the hidden input field, and the second is supposed to represent the value of the radio/star.

```js
$(document).on('click', 'fieldset', function () {
    console.log($(this).find("input[type='hidden']").val());
    console.log($(this).find("input[type='radio']:checked").val());
});
```

```css
fieldset,
label {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.rating {
  border: none;
  float: left;
}

.rating>input {
  display: none;
}

.rating>label:before {
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "\f005";
}

.rating>.half:before {
  content: "\f089";
  position: absolute;
}

.rating>label {
  color: #ddd;
  float: right;
}

.rating>input:checked~label,

/* show gold star when clicked */

.rating:not(:checked)>label:hover,

/* hover current star */

.rating:not(:checked)>label:hover~label {
  color: #FFD700;
}


/* hover previous stars in list */

.rating>input:checked+label:hover,

/* hover current star when changing rating */

.rating>input:checked~label:hover,
.rating>label:hover~input:checked~label,

/* lighten current selection */

.rating>input:checked~label:hover~label {
  color: #FFED85;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<fieldset class="rating">
<input type="hidden" value="1">
  <input type="radio" id="5star" name="rating" value="5" />
  <label class="full" for="5star" title="Excellent"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="4halfstar" name="rating" value="4.5" />
  <label class="half" for="4halfstar" title="Good"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="4star" name="rating" value="4" />
  <label class="full" for="4star" title="Pretty good"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="3halfstar" name="rating" value="3.5" />
  <label class="half" for="3halfstar" title="Nice"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="3star" name="rating" value="3" />
  <label class="full" for="3star" title="Ok"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="2halfstar" name="rating" value="2.5" />
  <label class="half" for="2halfstar" title="Kinda bad"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="2star" name="rating" value="2" />
  <label class="full" for="2star" title="Bad"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="1halfstar" name="rating" value="1.5" />
  <label class="half" for="1halfstar" title="Meh"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="1star" name="rating" value="1" />
  <label class="full" for="1star" title="Umm"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="halfstar" name="rating" value="0.5" />
  <label class="half" for="halfstar" title="Worst"></label>

</fieldset>

<br><br>

<fieldset class="rating">
<input type="hidden" value="2">
  <input type="radio" id="5star" name="rating" value="5" />
  <label class="full" for="5star" title="Excellent"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="4halfstar" name="rating" value="4.5" />
  <label class="half" for="4halfstar" title="Good"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="4star" name="rating" value="4" />
  <label class="full" for="4star" title="Pretty good"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="3halfstar" name="rating" value="3.5" />
  <label class="half" for="3halfstar" title="Nice"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="3star" name="rating" value="3" />
  <label class="full" for="3star" title="Ok"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="2halfstar" name="rating" value="2.5" />
  <label class="half" for="2halfstar" title="Kinda bad"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="2star" name="rating" value="2" />
  <label class="full" for="2star" title="Bad"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="1halfstar" name="rating" value="1.5" />
  <label class="half" for="1halfstar" title="Meh"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="1star" name="rating" value="1" />
  <label class="full" for="1star" title="Umm"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="halfstar" name="rating" value="0.5" />
  <label class="half" for="halfstar" title="Worst"></label>

</fieldset>
```

Comment: first, you are using the same name for the radio for both fieldset ... so they are considered together, you need to specfiy another name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem with you code is that clicking on `label` in a `fieldset` emits `click` event on the `input`. So you really have **two** clicks - first on label, second - on related `input radio`.

So, what you need to do is to track `change` event for `radio` instead tracking clicks on `fieldset`.

**Update:** And as Temani Afif mentioned in comments, as you have **non-unique** ids for inputs, clicking on `radio` in second `fieldset` still gets value of `input[type='hidden']` in **first** `fieldset`. So, you need to replace you labels ids **too**.

**More**: a better practice for `label`s is wraping `input` in it, so you have markup something like:

```
<label class="half" title="Good">
    <input type="radio" name="rating" value="4.5" />
</label>
```

In this case you don't need `id` and `for` as `label` works with element which is inside it.

```js
$(document).on('change', 'input[type="radio"]', function (e) {
    console.log(
        $(this).val(), 
        $(this).parent().find("input[type='hidden']").val()
    );
});
```

```css
fieldset,
label {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.rating {
  border: none;
  float: left;
}

.rating>input {
  display: none;
}

.rating>label:before {
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "\f005";
}

.rating>.half:before {
  content: "\f089";
  position: absolute;
}

.rating>label {
  color: #ddd;
  float: right;
}

.rating>input:checked~label,

/* show gold star when clicked */

.rating:not(:checked)>label:hover,

/* hover current star */

.rating:not(:checked)>label:hover~label {
  color: #FFD700;
}


/* hover previous stars in list */

.rating>input:checked+label:hover,

/* hover current star when changing rating */

.rating>input:checked~label:hover,
.rating>label:hover~input:checked~label,

/* lighten current selection */

.rating>input:checked~label:hover~label {
  color: #FFED85;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<fieldset class="rating">
<input type="hidden" value="1">
  <input type="radio" id="5star" name="rating" value="5" />
  <label class="full" for="5star" title="Excellent"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="4halfstar" name="rating" value="4.5" />
  <label class="half" for="4halfstar" title="Good"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="4star" name="rating" value="4" />
  <label class="full" for="4star" title="Pretty good"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="3halfstar" name="rating" value="3.5" />
  <label class="half" for="3halfstar" title="Nice"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="3star" name="rating" value="3" />
  <label class="full" for="3star" title="Ok"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="2halfstar" name="rating" value="2.5" />
  <label class="half" for="2halfstar" title="Kinda bad"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="2star" name="rating" value="2" />
  <label class="full" for="2star" title="Bad"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="1halfstar" name="rating" value="1.5" />
  <label class="half" for="1halfstar" title="Meh"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="1star" name="rating" value="1" />
  <label class="full" for="1star" title="Umm"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="halfstar" name="rating" value="0.5" />
  <label class="half" for="halfstar" title="Worst"></label>

</fieldset>

<br><br>

<fieldset class="rating">
<input type="hidden" value="2">
  <input type="radio" id="second-5star" name="rating" value="5" />
  <label class="full" for="second-5star" title="Excellent"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="second-4halfstar" name="rating" value="4.5" />
  <label class="half" for="second-4halfstar" title="Good"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="second-4star" name="rating" value="4" />
  <label class="full" for="second-4star" title="Pretty good"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="second-3halfstar" name="rating" value="3.5" />
  <label class="half" for="second-3halfstar" title="Nice"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="second-3star" name="rating" value="3" />
  <label class="full" for="second-3star" title="Ok"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="second-2halfstar" name="rating" value="2.5" />
  <label class="half" for="second-2halfstar" title="Kinda bad"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="second-2star" name="rating" value="2" />
  <label class="full" for="second-2star" title="Bad"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="second-1halfstar" name="rating" value="1.5" />
  <label class="half" for="second-1halfstar" title="Meh"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="second-1star" name="rating" value="1" />
  <label class="full" for="second-1star" title="Umm"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="second-halfstar" name="rating" value="0.5" />
  <label class="half" for="second-halfstar" title="Worst"></label>

</fieldset>
```

Comment: Wait ignore my last comment.. I tried your code, but the last fieldset outputs '1' when it should be '2' (the last number)

Comment: What would be an alternative to replacing the label ids, as they are dynamically created and it would be a lot of code to change them each time

Comment: See my **more** block, but it still needs mark up change.

Comment: Thank you! It seems to work by changing the HTML like you suggested