# Stars (radio button) won't change colour when selected

Tags: html, css

I have two star rating systems using `radio` buttons. When the user clicks the star, that star and all the stars behind it are supposed to turn yellow. You can see this in the comments in my CSS code (such as `/* show gold star when clicked */`).

I believe it has something to do with with the `::before` element which appears maybe? But I'm not totally sure on this:

[image]

```css
.rating {
  border: none;
  float: left;
}

.rating {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.rating input {
  display: none;
}

.rating label:before {
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "\f005";
}

.rating .half:before {
  content: "\f089";
  position: absolute;
}

.rating label {
  color: #ddd;
  float: right;
}

.rating input:checked~label,

/* show gold star when clicked */

.rating:not(:checked) label:hover,

/* hover current star */

.rating:not(:checked) label:hover~label {
  color: #FFD700;
}


/* hover previous stars in list */

.rating input:checked+label:hover,

/* hover current star when changing rating */

.rating input:checked~label:hover,
.rating label:hover~input:checked~label,

/* lighten current selection */

.rating input:checked~label:hover~label {
  color: #FFED85;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<fieldset class="rating">
  <label class="full" title="Excellent">
   <input type="radio" name="rating" value="5" />
   </label>
  <label class="half" title="Good">
   <input type="radio" name="rating" value="4.5" />
   </label>
  <label class="full" title="Pretty Good">
   <input type="radio" name="rating" value="4" />
   </label>
  <label class="half" title="Nice">
   <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3.5" />
   </label>
  <label class="full" title="Ok">
   <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3" />
   </label>
  <label class="half" title="Kinda Bad">
   <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2.5" />
   </label>
  <label class="full" title="Bad">
   <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2" />
   </label>
  <label class="half" title="Meh">
   <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1.5" />
   </label>
  <label class="full" title="Umm">
   <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1" />
   </label>
  <label class="half" title="Worst">
   <input type="radio" name="rating" value="0.5" />
   </label>
</fieldset>

<br><br>

<fieldset class="rating">
  <label class="full" title="Excellent">
   <input type="radio" name="rating" value="5" />
   </label>
  <label class="half" title="Good">
   <input type="radio" name="rating" value="4.5" />
   </label>
  <label class="full" title="Pretty Good">
   <input type="radio" name="rating" value="4" />
   </label>
  <label class="half" title="Nice">
   <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3.5" />
   </label>
  <label class="full" title="Ok">
   <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3" />
   </label>
  <label class="half" title="Kinda Bad">
   <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2.5" />
   </label>
  <label class="full" title="Bad">
   <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2" />
   </label>
  <label class="half" title="Meh">
   <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1.5" />
   </label>
  <label class="full" title="Umm">
   <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1" />
   </label>
  <label class="half" title="Worst">
   <input type="radio" name="rating" value="0.5" />
   </label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: You're trying to target the following items as siblings of your selected radio button, but because your buttons are wrapped in labels, they're not siblings (they're actually... cousins I guess? children of the parent's sibling). Because there's no parent selector in CSS, you'd need to move your inputs outside of their labels (or use JavaScript to polyfill the missing parent selector functionality).

Comment: @delinear I see. To avoid JS, is it possible to keep the same format (the buttons wrapped in labels), but create a parent container?

Comment: Unfortunately not, it's the :checked status of your buttons you are matching against, so the buttons all need to be on the same level (i.e. outside of their labels). It is still achievable in pure CSS, you'd just need to use `for=""` attributes on your labels and corresponding `id=""` attributes on your inputs.

Comment: @delinear yes that is the problem if you look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49351697/onclick-event-runs-twice i have to wrap the input inside the label

Comment: see my answer below, I've refactored the JavaScript you posted on the other answer slightly, does this now do what you want?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above, this is achievable in pure CSS, but it does require adding IDs and for attributes and restructuring the HTML a little to make the labels and radio buttons siblings, like so:

```js
$(document).on('click', 'fieldset label', function () {
    var that = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('hidden val=',$(that).parent().find("input[type='hidden']").val());
    console.log('checked val=',$(that).parent().find("input[type='radio']:checked").val());
    },1);
});
```

```css
.rating {
  border: none;
  float: left;
}

.rating {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.rating input {
  display: none;
}

.rating label:before {
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "\f005";
}

.rating .half:before {
  content: "\f089";
  position: absolute;
}

.rating label {
  color: #ddd;
  float: right;
}

.rating input:checked~label,

/* show gold star when clicked */

.rating:not(:checked) label:hover,

/* hover current star */

.rating:not(:checked) label:hover~label {
  color: #FFD700;
}


/* hover previous stars in list */

.rating input:checked+label:hover,

/* hover current star when changing rating */

.rating input:checked~label:hover,
.rating label:hover~input:checked~label,

/* lighten current selection */

.rating input:checked~label:hover~label {
  color: #FFED85;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<fieldset class="rating">
<input type="hidden" value="1">
  <input type="radio" id="5star" name="rating" value="5" />
  <label class="full" for="5star" title="Excellent"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="4halfstar" name="rating" value="4.5" />
  <label class="half" for="4halfstar" title="Good"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="4star" name="rating" value="4" />
  <label class="full" for="4star" title="Pretty good"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="3halfstar" name="rating" value="3.5" />
  <label class="half" for="3halfstar" title="Nice"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="3star" name="rating" value="3" />
  <label class="full" for="3star" title="Ok"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="2halfstar" name="rating" value="2.5" />
  <label class="half" for="2halfstar" title="Kinda bad"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="2star" name="rating" value="2" />
  <label class="full" for="2star" title="Bad"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="1halfstar" name="rating" value="1.5" />
  <label class="half" for="1halfstar" title="Meh"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="1star" name="rating" value="1" />
  <label class="full" for="1star" title="Umm"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="halfstar" name="rating" value="0.5" />
  <label class="half" for="halfstar" title="Worst"></label>

</fieldset>

<br><br>

<fieldset class="rating">
<input type="hidden" value="2">
  <input type="radio" id="5star2" name="rating2" value="5" />
  <label class="full" for="5star2" title="Excellent"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="4halfstar2" name="rating2" value="4.5" />
  <label class="half" for="4halfstar2" title="Good"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="4star2" name="rating2" value="4" />
  <label class="full" for="4star2" title="Pretty good"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="3halfstar2" name="rating2" value="3.5" />
  <label class="half" for="3halfstar2" title="Nice"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="3star2" name="rating2" value="3" />
  <label class="full" for="3star2" title="Ok"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="2halfstar2" name="rating2" value="2.5" />
  <label class="half" for="2halfstar2" title="Kinda bad"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="2star2" name="rating2" value="2" />
  <label class="full" for="2star2" title="Bad"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="1halfstar2" name="rating2" value="1.5" />
  <label class="half" for="1halfstar2" title="Meh"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="1star2" name="rating2" value="1" />
  <label class="full" for="1star2" title="Umm"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="halfstar2" name="rating2" value="0.5" />
  <label class="half" for="halfstar2" title="Worst"></label>

</fieldset>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply and sorry for the late response. Would you possibly be able to alter your code so there is two star rating systems as in my question please

Comment: Sure, take a look at my update - you basically almost had it working the first time, you just need to ensure your `id` and `name` values are unique (per element in the case of id and per fieldset in the case of name) and a small tweak to your JavaScript selector. Hope this helps!