# Two star rating systems always outputs the ID of the second one's parent ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The issue is I have two star rating systems. Each star rating system's parent `fieldset` has a different ID. If the user clicks the first star rating system, I want it to output that parent container's ID and if they click the second star rating system, I want it to output that parent container's ID.

However, both star rating systems output the ID of the second (last) fieldset container.

```js
$(document).on('change', 'input[type="radio"]', function (e) {
        console.log($(this).parent().attr('id'));
});
```

```css
fieldset,
label {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.rating {
  border: none;
  float: left;
}

.rating>input {
  display: none;
}

.rating>label:before {
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "\f005";
}

.rating>.half:before {
  content: "\f089";
  position: absolute;
}

.rating>label {
  color: #ddd;
  float: right;
}

.rating>input:checked~label,

/* show gold star when clicked */

.rating:not(:checked)>label:hover,

/* hover current star */

.rating:not(:checked)>label:hover~label {
  color: #FFD700;
}


/* hover previous stars in list */

.rating>input:checked+label:hover,

/* hover current star when changing rating */

.rating>input:checked~label:hover,
.rating>label:hover~input:checked~label,

/* lighten current selection */

.rating>input:checked~label:hover~label {
  color: #FFED85;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<fieldset class="rating" id="93">
  <input type="radio" id="5star" name="rating" value="5" />
  <label class="full" for="5star" title="Excellent"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="4halfstar" name="rating" value="4.5" />
  <label class="half" for="4halfstar" title="Good"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="4star" name="rating" value="4" />
  <label class="full" for="4star" title="Pretty good"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="3halfstar" name="rating" value="3.5" />
  <label class="half" for="3halfstar" title="Nice"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="3star" name="rating" value="3" />
  <label class="full" for="3star" title="Ok"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="2halfstar" name="rating" value="2.5" />
  <label class="half" for="2halfstar" title="Kinda bad"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="2star" name="rating" value="2" />
  <label class="full" for="2star" title="Bad"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="1halfstar" name="rating" value="1.5" />
  <label class="half" for="1halfstar" title="Meh"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="1star" name="rating" value="1" />
  <label class="full" for="1star" title="Umm"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="halfstar" name="rating" value="0.5" />
  <label class="half" for="halfstar" title="Worst"></label>

</fieldset>

<br><br>

<fieldset class="rating" id="23">
  <input type="radio" id="5star" name="rating" value="5" />
  <label class="full" for="5star" title="Excellent"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="4halfstar" name="rating" value="4.5" />
  <label class="half" for="4halfstar" title="Good"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="4star" name="rating" value="4" />
  <label class="full" for="4star" title="Pretty good"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="3halfstar" name="rating" value="3.5" />
  <label class="half" for="3halfstar" title="Nice"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="3star" name="rating" value="3" />
  <label class="full" for="3star" title="Ok"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="2halfstar" name="rating" value="2.5" />
  <label class="half" for="2halfstar" title="Kinda bad"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="2star" name="rating" value="2" />
  <label class="full" for="2star" title="Bad"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="1halfstar" name="rating" value="1.5" />
  <label class="half" for="1halfstar" title="Meh"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="1star" name="rating" value="1" />
  <label class="full" for="1star" title="Umm"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="halfstar" name="rating" value="0.5" />
  <label class="half" for="halfstar" title="Worst"></label>

</fieldset>
```

---

If you have a look at my question [Onclick event runs twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49351697/onclick-event-runs-twice), you will see that the answer was either to :

- Give each input a unique ID (since their are two sets of star rating systems)
- Change the HTML structure so that each input is inside a label.

Unfortunately none of these really help as the first option isn't convenient to change the ID for each star rating set and with the second option, it mucks up my CSS as seen here [Stars (radio button) won't change colour when selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49368221/stars-radio-button-wont-change-colour-when-selected)

What should I do?

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Comment: @j08691 Yes the issue seems to surround the id. Would it be possible to remove the id altogether or something like that? Because I really don't want to muck around with changing each id for the different star ratings

Comment: _"Would it be possible to remove the id altogether"_ Seeing as how your CSS doesn't select via ID it should be possible, but then you obviously couldn't console log the ID

Comment: @j08691 but i only console.log the id of the `fieldset` which the `input` is in

Comment: Actually both output the id of the **first** fieldset, which is logical because the `<label for=` will always trigger changes on the set of inputs of fieldset `#93`. Either use unique id's (e.g `93_4star` and `23_4star`), or remove them altogether (but if you do this you'll have to attach a click handler to each label as the for attrs won't trigger changes). You probably also want to prefix the `name` attribute unless both fieldsets reference one and the same rating, otherwise you'll have the same value for both fieldsets `[name="rating"]`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is indeed **duplicate IDs**, since you don't want to do it manually (understandable) maybe because there are hundreds or whatever reason. Following approach is post-processing the already generated markup (if you are generating it yourself, just follow the same technique AS you generate them, instead of AFTER).

Like this, each `input` will have its own unique id and (VERY IMPORTANT!) also will the corresponding `label` have the necessary `for` attribute.

Feel free to refactor for efficiency.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('fieldset').each(function(){
          var parentId = $(this).attr('id');
          $(this).children('input').each(function(){
            var newId = $(this).attr('id') + "-" + parentId;
            $(this).attr('id', $(this).attr('id') + "-" + parentId);
            $(this).next('label').attr('for', newId);
        });
        });
});

$(document).on('change', 'input[type="radio"]', function (e) {
        console.log($(this).parent().attr('id'));
});
```

```css
fieldset,
label {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.rating {
  border: none;
  float: left;
}

.rating>input {
  display: none;
}

.rating>label:before {
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "\f005";
}

.rating>.half:before {
  content: "\f089";
  position: absolute;
}

.rating>label {
  color: #ddd;
  float: right;
}

.rating>input:checked~label,

/* show gold star when clicked */

.rating:not(:checked)>label:hover,

/* hover current star */

.rating:not(:checked)>label:hover~label {
  color: #FFD700;
}


/* hover previous stars in list */

.rating>input:checked+label:hover,

/* hover current star when changing rating */

.rating>input:checked~label:hover,
.rating>label:hover~input:checked~label,

/* lighten current selection */

.rating>input:checked~label:hover~label {
  color: #FFED85;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<fieldset class="rating" id="93">
  <input type="radio" id="5star" name="rating" value="5" />
  <label class="full" for="5star" title="Excellent"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="4halfstar" name="rating" value="4.5" />
  <label class="half" for="4halfstar" title="Good"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="4star" name="rating" value="4" />
  <label class="full" for="4star" title="Pretty good"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="3halfstar" name="rating" value="3.5" />
  <label class="half" for="3halfstar" title="Nice"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="3star" name="rating" value="3" />
  <label class="full" for="3star" title="Ok"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="2halfstar" name="rating" value="2.5" />
  <label class="half" for="2halfstar" title="Kinda bad"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="2star" name="rating" value="2" />
  <label class="full" for="2star" title="Bad"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="1halfstar" name="rating" value="1.5" />
  <label class="half" for="1halfstar" title="Meh"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="1star" name="rating" value="1" />
  <label class="full" for="1star" title="Umm"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="halfstar" name="rating" value="0.5" />
  <label class="half" for="halfstar" title="Worst"></label>

</fieldset>

<br><br>

<fieldset class="rating" id="23">
  <input type="radio" id="5star" name="rating" value="5" />
  <label class="full" for="5star" title="Excellent"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="4halfstar" name="rating" value="4.5" />
  <label class="half" for="4halfstar" title="Good"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="4star" name="rating" value="4" />
  <label class="full" for="4star" title="Pretty good"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="3halfstar" name="rating" value="3.5" />
  <label class="half" for="3halfstar" title="Nice"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="3star" name="rating" value="3" />
  <label class="full" for="3star" title="Ok"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="2halfstar" name="rating" value="2.5" />
  <label class="half" for="2halfstar" title="Kinda bad"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="2star" name="rating" value="2" />
  <label class="full" for="2star" title="Bad"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="1halfstar" name="rating" value="1.5" />
  <label class="half" for="1halfstar" title="Meh"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="1star" name="rating" value="1" />
  <label class="full" for="1star" title="Umm"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="halfstar" name="rating" value="0.5" />
  <label class="half" for="halfstar" title="Worst"></label>

</fieldset>
```